# HTML/JS: Setting "100% auto" for background-size property truncates to "100%" but "auto 100%" does not

Tags: javascript, html, css

For a div, why does setting "100% auto" for the background-size property get truncated to "100%" but "auto 100%" does not?

The goal is to allow "100% auto" for the background-size property.

"100% auto" is different from "100%", isn't it?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xMLXKz?editors=1111

```
<div id="test1"></div>
<div id="test2"></div>

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}

$("#test1")[0].style["background-size"] = "100% auto";
$("#test2")[0].style["background-size"] = "auto 100%";

console.log($("#test1")[0].style["background-size"]);
console.log($("#test2")[0].style["background-size"]);

console.log("Done")
```

This outputs:

```
"100%"
"auto 100%"
"Done"
```

Comment: It's working totally fine ( as expected as well ) in FireFox. Let me check in other browsers.

Comment: @mrReiha does not work on chrome

Comment: since `100%` is a correct value for `background-size` and it evaluates to `100% auto` chrome doesn't include `auto` keyword at all. it seems to be safe if you check for a `/\s/` character in value and if it wasn't there, append an `auto` to it.

Comment: @mrReiha `100%` evaluates to `100% auto` or `100% 100%`?

Comment: it's equal to `100% auto` just like `flex` property which this example `flex: 1 1` is equal to `flex: 1 1 auto`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can check [here at MDN - background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size), it clearly says when the second value ( i.e. height ) is absent, the browser will treat as `auto`.

So, I think it's okay to check for a `/\s/` character in your `$("#test1")[0].style["background-size"]` value to check for a space, and if it wasn't there ( RegExp returned `-1` ) append an `auto` to the output to become `100% auto`.